# Ng-Repeat with one JSONObject and JSONArray

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi Can anyone please help me in getting the solution for the below problem

Currently I am getting JSON response from AngularJS

```
  $scope.bepValues = $scope.aftCnv.Events.Event;
```

And I am facing issue in using Ng-Repeat when I am having only 1 Event in Events Tag. But The same is working When I am getting more than 1 Events in Events array.

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in bepValues">
<td class="features" >{{list.Body.WorkOrder.OrderStatus}}</td>
```

Console Log Value with 1Event

```
Object {Header: Object, Body: Object}
```

[image: Image with only 1 Event]

Console Log Value with more than 1 EEPEvent

```
[Object, Object]
```

[image: Image with more than 1 Event]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **ng-if** to check whether it is array. If it is an array then use **ng-repeat** else use single **tr** tag to display the value.

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in bepValues">
   <td class="features">{{list.Body.WorkOrder.OrderStatus}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-if="!bepValues.length">
    <td>{{bepValues.Body.WorkOrder.OrderStatus}}</td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT:**

If you have multiple such cases then create a **filter** to return array if only one object is present:

```
MyApp.filter('formatArray', [function(){
    return function(array){
        if(angular.isUndefined(array.length)){ // Check for object type
            array = [array]; // Convert it into array of single object
        }
        return array;
    }
}]);
```

Add **formatArray** filter to your template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in bepValues | formatArray">
   <td class="features">{{list.Body.WorkOrder.OrderStatus}}</td>
</tr>
```

For object type **ng-repeat** will loop only once.

Comment: Like this I have around 20 expressions  to display so is there any way i can handle it in easy way instead of using ng-if for all the 20 expressions..